# Переход по input javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, не получается одна задачка есть 3 input'а нужно что бы при вводе в первый трёх символов focus переходил на другой input так же и при вводе во второй переходило на третий. И то же самое с удалением из них т.е. если я удалил все символы с 3 input фокус перешел на второй, а при удалении со второго на первый

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="inp1"  maxlength="3"  size="3">
    <input type="text" id="inp2"  maxlength="3"  size="3">
    <input type="text" id="inp3"  maxlength="4"  size="4">
   
</form>
```

Comment: Если не получается решить задачу, то наверное вы уже какие-то наработки имеете. Закиньте их плиз

Answer (score 3):

Каждый раз формируем строку и раскидываем по инпутам.
Вероятно, не будет работать на iOS из-за вызова `inp.focus()`.
Желательно добавить обработку стрелок.
Желательно добавить обработку <kbd>Delete</kbd> и <kbd>Backspace</kbd> в конце и начале поля соответственно.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var inp = event.target;
  var inps = this.querySelectorAll('input');
  var value = Array.prototype.map.call(inps, x => x.value).join('');
  var i = +inp.dataset.start + inp.selectionStart, pos = value.length;
  
  for (var q=0; q<inps.length; ++q) {
    var start = +inps[q].dataset.start, len = +inps[q].dataset.len;
    inps[q].value = value.substr(start, len);
    
    if (start + len >= i) {
      inp = inps[q];
      pos = i - start;
      i = NaN;
    }
  }
  
  inp.focus();
  inp.selectionStart = inp.selectionEnd = pos;
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="inp" data-start="0" data-len="3" size="3">
  <input type="text" name="inp" data-start="3" data-len="3" size="3">
  <input type="text" name="inp" data-start="6" data-len="4" size="4">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: А как его подключать, просто если его вставить между <script> он у меня не работает, видимо я что-то не так делаю

Answer (score 0):

```js
function jmp(e){
    var max = ~~e.getAttribute('maxlength');
    if(max && e.value.length >= max){
        do{
            e = e.nextSibling;
        }
        while(e && !(/text/.test(e.type)));
        if(e && /text/.test(e.type)){
            e.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Введите серийный номер</p>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="jmp(this);" maxlength="5" size="5">-
    <input type="text" onkeyup="jmp(this);" maxlength="4" size="4">-
    <input type="text" onkeyup="jmp(this);" maxlength="7" size="7">-
    <input type="text" onkeyup="jmp(this);" maxlength="5" size="5">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но нужно чтоб еще при удалении оно перескакивало обратно. Я  честно говоря, сейчас не очень понимаю что происходит в цикле while поэтому переделать не могу и если я правильно понял то для того чтоб перескакивало обратно нужно использовать previoussibling?