# Криво работает атрибут 'maxlength' в input

Tags: html5

Сразу оговорюсь: данная тема поднималась тут, но ответ в ней не дан.

Делаю блок с вводом данных с пластиковой карты. Есть 4 input , в них должен быть ввод только цифр и не более 4.

```
<div class="card__input-num">
    <input class="input card__input-num_item" type="number" min="1" max="4" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="input card__input-num_item" type="number" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="4" min="4" max="4">
    <input class="input card__input-num_item" type="number autocomplete="off"  maxlength="4">
    <input class="input card__input-num_item" type="number" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4">
</div>
```

[image: Вот как это все отображается]
-В первом input вводятся только цифры и только 4 ( кстати англ. буква "e" почему-то тоже можно ввести).

-Во втором то же самое. Оно и понятно.

-В третьем случайно забрал одну двойную кавычку после type="number - и о чудо! Вводить можно не более 4х цифр ! Но теперь и буквы так же доступны для ввода, ясно почему, но не ясно почему maxlength="4" заработал!?

min/max тоже никак заставить работать ? Или я что-то делаю не так ?

Comment: ``maxlength`` для ``number`` не работает. Используйте ``text`` и валидируйте на корректный ввод.

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не надо использовать тип `number` для текстовых данных - лидирующие нули ввести не получится.
2. Надо делать примерно так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687383/178988
3. Только добавить валидацию, что вводятся только цифры.
4. Ещё можно атрибут `pattern="\d+"` добавить - вроде бы на некоторых телефонах в таком случае отобразится цифровая клавиатура вместо стандартной.

Answer (score 1):

дополню вот это:

> кстати англ. буква "e" почему-то тоже можно ввести

это потому, что число (`number`) может быть не только целым и записано не только в десятичном счислении и не только в привычном нам виде. 0xFF, 3.5e4 - тоже числа (255 и 35000).

Answer (score 0):

Как в комментарии к вопросу констатировал @Эникейщик `maxlength` для `number` не работает. или используйте `type="text"` или добавьте JS. Самый базовый пример:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4">

<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
    type = "number"
    maxlength = "4"
 />
```